# Extended partition automatically created and the 3rd partition volume is labelled "partition 5" after clean install

Tags: partitioning, usb-installation

I recently had to re-install Ubuntu after (foolishly) renaming the home dir before copying and moving it to another disk. I chose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu 20.04.1" to perform a fresh install (via usb), however I noticed that the disk partitioning was automatically split into 3 volumes. The second volume (partition 2) was automatically created as an extended partition and the third volume was labelled partition 5? [see link below]

[Example of odd(?) partitioning after install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TIMm.png)

As I'm a newcomer to Ubuntu I have two questions regarding this:

1. Why was an extended partition automatically created during the install and can/should I delete it?
2. Why is the third volume labelled "partition 5" instead of "partition 3" and will this cause issues later down the line?

Comment: Why are you using MBR partitioning?  IMO reinstall *again*.. wipe your disk ahead of time and make sure it's GPT - then make sure you're booting the installation media as UEFI

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!
Yes there were two options for booting the USB in BIOS, so I likely did not select UEFI. I'll re-install again and see what happens.

Comment: Yes I didn't select UEFI! It's GPT and the volume partitioning is normal now. Thanks again for the fast response Nmath!